# How to define java.awt.Rectangle using 4 points?

Tags: java, awt

I want to draw a rectangle with the four 4 corners at `A(16,14) B(12,18) C(8,14) D(12,10)`. I then want to check if the point `P(12,11)` is inside the rectangle or not.

Is it possible to achieve this using `java.awt.Rectangle`?

I tried the code below and not working as desired (reports that `1, 1` is inside the rectangle, when it is clearly not):

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(16, 14);
bounds.add(12, 18);
bounds.add(8, 14);
bounds.add(12, 10);

System.out.println(bounds.contains(1,1)); // printing true which is not right
```

Comment: If you know all 4 point coordinates you don't need to use any additional classes to know if your point falls inside it. Try comparing your point's X and Y coordinates to the ranges of X and Y in the 4 corner points.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Added code to question

Comment: @AlexR Rectangle is not parallel to axes. So checking the point will become complex. hope `java.awt.Rectangle` can simply the problem

Comment: What do you mean, not working as expected?

Comment: @MadPhysicist point 1,1 is not inside for rectangle with given points. But code is printing true.

Comment: Ah, in haste I assumed they were parallel because of the 12/12 and 14/14. My mistake. Obviously that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, are you trying to check `11, 12` or `1, 1`?

Comment: Finally, are you expecting something like `16, 18` to be in the rectangle? If so, you may want to see the update in my answer.

Comment: Why did you unaccept? Did you encounter any other problems? If it is related to this one, feel free to tell me. If it is not, please do some research first, then you can consider asking another question.

Comment: Answer by Mad Physicist gave the solution. Your answer had some limitation which I figured out later. His answer gave better info than yours. Here I can't accept more than 1 answer. Sorry about that.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clear that the four points are the corners, not just some random points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`java.awt.Rectangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) is not the right tool for the job you have in mind. `Rectangles` are used to represent screen drawing areas with sides that are always parallel to the axes of the x-y coordinate system. There is no provision for angle of rotation. The quadrilateral you are specifying is rotated, so checking the bounds on a `Rectangle` will include a point like `(8, 13)`, which you don't want. See the diagram below:

[image]

A better choice would be [`java.awt.Polygon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html). You could construct it via

```
Polygon p = new Polygon(new int[] {16, 12, 8, 12}, new int[] {14, 18, 14, 10}, 4);
```

or alternatively

```
Polygon p = new Polygon();
p.addPoint(16, 14);
p.addPoint(12, 18);
p.addPoint(8, 14);
p.addPoint(12, 10);
```

The main issue with using `Polygon` is that it is intended for manipulating graphical elements and is not really designed to handle non-integer math very well. If you read the docs for [`Polygon.contains(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains-double-double-double-double-) and follow the link that explains the definition of insideness, you will see that `Polygon` has the same issue as `Regtangle` on its lower-left boundary. A way to work around that is to use [`Polygon.contains(x, y, 1, 1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#contains-double-double-double-double-), but that seems like overkill.

A better option may be to use the classes in [`java.awt.geom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/package-summary.html). My personal recommendation would be to use [`Path2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html). [`Path2D.Float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Float.html) and [`GeneralPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) are also options, but they have limited precision. If that is OK with you, use `Path2D.Float` for a preference.

You would construct the path using the [default constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#Double--):

```
Path2D.Double p = new Path2D.Double();
```

You can ignore the capacity and winding since you have a tiny and convex shape. Now fill in the path using [`moveTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#moveTo-double-double-) to start the path, [`lineTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#lineTo-double-double-) to add points, and then [`closePath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#closePath--) to complete the rectangle and make containment work:

```
p.moveTo(16, 14);
p.lineTo(12, 18);
p.lineTo(8, 14);
p.lineTo(12, 10);
p.closePath();
```

Now you should see that the point `(8, 13)` is indeed outside your shape:

```
System.out.println(p.contains(8, 13));
```

Same goes for `(1, 1)`:

```
System.out.println(p.contains(1, 1));
```

Comment: @Gasol. Thank you for that. I can't believe I never noticed it before.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful to me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a rectangle with 4 points is quite easy.

First, you need to select an arbitrary point and assign the point's x and y to `x` and `y` respectively. Then, create a rectangle with the arguments `(x, y, 0, 0)`. After that, call `add` three times to add the other points.

In your case, this would work:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(8, 14, 0, 0); // 8 and 14 are the smallerst x and y
rect.add(16, 14);
rect.add(12, 18);
rect.add(12, 10);
System.out.println(rect.contains(1,1)); // false
```

I have written a method for you:

```
public static Rectangle createRectangeWithPoints(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4) {
    int x = p1.getX();
    int y = p1.getY();
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 0, 0);
    rect.add(p2);
    rect.add(p3);
    rect.add(p4);
    return rect;
}
```

Comment: This is a bit of overkill, no? You don't need any of the math code at all, just the other constructor.

Comment: Which constructor?@MadPhysicist

Comment: The one you are using.

Comment: I'm just saying you don't need to compute the origin. `add` will do that for you once you have the right constructor (which you do).

Comment: @MadPhysicist oh I see what you mean! I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is clever, but you are using the wrong constructor for `Rectangle`. The two-int constructor is [`Rectangle(int width, int height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int%29), and it implicitly sets the upper-left corner to `(0, 0)`, which is why your code prints `true`.

You need to specify your first point as the upper-left corner to a zero-width rectangle before adding the remaining point. Use the four-int constructor for this: [`Rectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#Rectangle%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(16, 14, 0, 0);
bounds.add(12, 18);
bounds.add(8, 14);
bounds.add(12, 10);

System.out.println(bounds.contains(1,1));
```

Now keep in mind the following quote from the docs for [`Rectangle.add(Point)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#add%28java.awt.Point%29):

> After adding a point, a call to contains with the added point as an argument does not necessarily return true. The contains method does not return true for points on the right or bottom edges of a Rectangle. Therefore, if the added point falls on the right or bottom edge of the enlarged Rectangle, contains returns false for that point. If the specified point must be contained within the new Rectangle, a 1x1 rectangle should be added instead:
>
> ```
> r.add(newx, newy, 1, 1);
> ```

As OP pointed out in his comment, this is technically incorrect, since there is no corresponding four-int `add` method. However, the `add(Rectangle)` method can be used if your rectangle is a mathematical construct rather than a drawn object:

```
Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(16, 14, 1, 1);
bounds.add(new Rectangle(12, 18, 1, 1));
bounds.add(new Rectangle(8, 14, 1, 1));
bounds.add(new Rectangle(12, 10, 1, 1));

System.out.println(bounds.contains(1,1));
```

Comment: add function either take `(x,y)` or `(height,width)`. But it won't accepts both. So `bounds.add(12,18)` will work. But `bounds.add(12,18,1,1)` is not correct.

Comment: @SantoshHegde. Thanks for the catch. That is an error in the docs and I have updated my description accordingly.

Comment: @SantoshHegde. I posted a bug report to Oracle about this mistake.

Comment: `bounds.contains(8,13)` returning true. But `P(8,13)` is not inside the rectangle.

Comment: @SantoshHegde. The rectangle is not tilted. Here is a link with a picture showing why `8, 13` is in fact within the rectangle.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmHMr.png. The blue dots are your points. The red `x` is `8, 13`.

Comment: if I join all 4 points, `8,13` lies outside the rectangle right?

Comment: @SantoshHegde. Ooooooh. In that case, `java.awt.Rectangle` will not work at all. I am going to go ahead and post a different answer.

Comment: @SantoshHegde. Just an FYI, here is an excerpt from the automated email noifying my that my bug report to Oracle was submitted successfully: > We have finished evaluating your report and have assigned it a Bug ID: JDK-8176040. The issue is visible on bugs.java.com at the following url
[JDK-8176040](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8176040). Thanks again for catching that.